# Gateway failover using netplan

Tags: ip-address, gateway, netplan, failover

I'm having trouble setting up 2 IP address so that if one fails it will use the secondary IP address. I've setup netplan as shown in the picture.
I can connect via ssh using both IP address, I test which IP address is the main one by using speedtest-cli, using the server control panel I disable the IP address that was used by speedtest-cli. However, when I try to use speedtest-cli again it doesn't work, I expected it to automatically switch to the IP that is still available. I tried pinging known IP address but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why this isn't working as I expect it to and how I can get it working? [image]

Comment: I do not know how your control panel disables an IP address, but the routes will need to be updated in that event.  You mention `netplan` which appears to have that functionality, though we would need to see the `netplan` configuration you are attempting to use to provide any useful assistance.

Comment: I thought I added a photo of the netplan configuration but it must not have uploaded. I've edited it to include the netplan configuration now.